# Передать переменную в postgresql запрос и выбрать значения с переданного id

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, psycopg2

Подскажите пожалуйста с логикой и реализацией.
Каким образом можно реализовать следующую логику:
Через запрос в коде формируется список

```
some_query_1 = """SELECT id, pas_id, date_add, status_id 
FROM table_1 
where status_id !=7 
group by id, pas_id, date_add, status_id 
order by date_add desc limit 50"""
cur.execute(some_query_1)
data_frame_from_first_table = cur.fetchall()

some_query_2 = """select id from table_1 order by date_add desc limit 1"""
cur.execute(some_query_2)
id_ = cur.fetchone()[0]

data_frame_from_some_query_1_to_frame = pd.DataFrame(data_frame_from_first_table, columns=['id','pas_id','date_add','status_id'] )
status_id_from_some_query_1_to_list = some_query_1.groupby('pas_id').agg(tuple)['status_id'].to_list()

dict = {
(2,4):'1',
(4,2):'2',
(2,1):'3',
(1,0):'4',
(1,1):'5',
(4,1):'6'
}
d_to_list =list(dict_of_right_transitions.keys())
check_combination = set(dict_of_right_transitions)
```

Вывод:

```
some_query_1 = [(2, 4, 2, 1, 0), (4, 2, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (4, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1, 1)]
some_query_2 = 5463
```

Есть таблица, где записи сгруппированы по id (3 айдишника одной записи, потом 4 другой и тд.). У этих записей есть поле статус. У статусов есть разрешенный переход (например из статуса 1 в статус 0 можно, а из 1 в 3 нельзя). Ключи словаря - разрешенные переходы. Мне нужно получить статусы в виде списка кортежей (`status_id_from_some_query_1_to_list` ), сравнить его со списком разрешенных статусов и получить айди записи, где комбинация статусов не разрешена. Проблема в том, что у одной записи может быть 4 статуса, а в словаре разрешенных комбинации представлены парами. Я не знаю как сравнить.
нужно как-то разбить каждый элемент списка кортежей на пары (на примере первого элмента списка кортежей `((2,4),(4,2)(2,1),(1,0))` второй элемент (`(4,2),(2,1),(1,0)`) и тд)
Затем после повторного запуска скрипта нужно чтобы проверка начиналась с стой записи, на которой закончилась в предыдущий раз. Для этого создана переменная `id_` , она хранит айди последней записи.

Comment: Начните с того, что получите результат второго запроса точно так же как и первого через `cur.fetchall()` и посмотрите, что там вернулось, оттуда можно будет извлечь `id`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, простите. Сейчас исправлю. Просто а качестве id он возвращает список кортежей из одного элемента ```[(34112,)]```

Comment: Если не путаю, можно просто `.fetch` в данном случае использовать, когда одна строка возвращается. Уже вернётся просто кортеж. Ну и возьмите от него нулевой элемент `id_ = cur.fetch()[0]`

Comment: @CrazyElf,  получилось

`id_ = cur.fetchone()[0]`

вывод;
`34112`

Comment: Ну а дальше наверное нужно записывать это значение в файл, а при старте скрипта читать из файла. Ну или просто делать второй запрос, а потом первый, подставив туда это значение

Comment: @CrazyElf, то есть, получить `id` из второго запроса и передать его в первый. А как сделать чтобы первый запрос начал проверку со значения первого запроса?

Comment: `id_, = cur.fetchone() or (None,)` Поскольку если ваш запрос ничего не вернет, то `cur.fetchone()`  вернет None и вы при `cur.fetchone()[0]` получите исключение. Кроме этого, совершенно не понятно нафиг вам в первом запросе группировка если там нет агрегирующих функций, если хотите избавиться от дубликатов, обычного `distinct` будет более чем достаточно. Если попробуете как-то более внятно обрисовать алгоритм (без определений типа "с неким словарем"), можно будет попробовать написать ответ.

Comment: @Namerek, постарался написать более внятно

Comment: Я наверно погорячился с просьбой описать алгоритм. Давайте проще, прошу Вас объяснить что Вы имеет (какие данные в каком формате) и что в результате хотите получить (опустив все подробности, только описания исходников и желаемого результата). К примеру - "есть таблица с такой-то структурой и вот такими данными, из нее хочу получить вот такой набор данных".

Comment: @Namerek, постарался описать